# Find the upper triangle in an n x nCr matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

Given matrix n x nCr, find the boolean matrix of unique combinations:

For n x n, this is trivial, the boolean matrix of unique combinations:

```
[['AA', 'AB', 'AC'],
 ['BA', 'BB', 'BC'],
 ['CA', 'CB', 'CC']]
```

The unique combinations when n=3 is:

```py
> mask = np.arange(3)[:, np.newaxis] < np.arange(3)
array([[False,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False]])
```

Okay, now when n=7 and r=2 and n x nCr matrix:

```
  AB AC AD AE AF AG BC BD BE BF BG CD CE CF CG DE DF DG EF EG FG <- 7C2 
A  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
B  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 
C  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1
D  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1
E  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
F  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
G  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

I'm trying to find a way when n=7 and c=2 to find a 7x21 (i.e. 7x7C2) matrix of boolean values with the truth values in the correct place. i.e. at the places giving me ABC, ACD, ABE, ABF...EFG

Clearly it's not a triangle, but what function can I apply such that I can create a mask which returns a 7x21 matrix of the correct boolean values.

I'm actually dealing with > 50 combination so ideally I wouldn't be building a 21x21 matrix and then slicing out what I don't need as it's a very memory sensitive problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little trial-and-error, I came up with this:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import comb

def comb_upper_triangular(n, r):
    k = comb(n, r, exact=True)
    ut = np.zeros((n, k), dtype=int)

    for i in range(n - r):
        ut[i, -comb(n - i - 1, r, exact=True):] = 1

    return ut
```

So for `comb_upper_triangular(7, 2)` we get:

```py
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

For an alternative pure numpy (and scipy) solution, we can use mgrid:

```py
def comb_upper_triangular2(n, r):
    k = comb(n, r, exact=True)
    x, y = np.mgrid[:n, :k]
    return (comb(n - x - 1, r) > np.fliplr(y)).astype(int)
```

This solution creates a several large arrays in memory, but avoids the python loop.

Comment: That's a really neat solution.

Comment: Part of me was hoping for a 1 line array broadcasting solution (if it is even possible!) or a clean math approach - I'm going to keep having a think, but will accept your answer in the next day or so if I can't come up with one!

Comment: I've updated with a pure numpy solution; it's still far from a one-liner though.  Maybe it will give you more ideas though.

Comment: Just benchmarked it, your first one is currently 10 times faster than mine.